# Role changing action. who does it belong to?

Tags: uml, use-case

If a user has the chance of asking for his role to be changed (for example : an employee asking to be promoted to leader ). Does the action belong to the Employee or to the leader ?

Comment: `an employee asking to be promoted to leader` : so the role interacting with the system is employee

Comment: Depends on how you modeled the role. Please clarify.

Comment: A user with the role "employee" can login, list stuff,add some other stuff, but never touch anything that a "leader" can. 
A "leader" is actually an "employee" but with more privileges (heritage).
An employee can make a request if he things he is qualified enough to become a leader.
Hope this clarifes.

Comment: `A user with the role "employee" can login` : warning with the wording, an employee had login but the actor (trying to) login is not an employee. Do not confuse a person (I mean a physical person, you me etc) and a role (e.g. an actor in UML sense), a person can have several roles, let say a guest whose interact to the system to login, an employee whose can interact with the system to list etc and logout, a leader (inheriting employee) can have other interactions etc. My first remark is unchanged

Comment: So for example, a guest can visit the home page and see the stuff on the home page. he may also login but that doesn't make him an employee because his login attempt may fail.
An employee is someone who already logged in and can do his employee stuff and may ask to be promoted but that doesn't make him a leader.
a leader is someone who has already been promoted . is that it ?

Comment: `a guest ... may also login but that doesn't make him an employee because his login attempt may fail` : it seems you still do not understand what an actor (role) is, *guest* and *employee* are two different actors (roles), and an actor cannot 'become' an other one. A physical person (or other entity) can have several roles and 'move' from a role to an other, but the actors are non mutable. In the same way a physical person can be promoted but the actor *employee* is not mutable and cannot become a *leader*.

Comment: `An employee is someone who already logged` / `a leader is someone who has already been promoted` : in the real life yes but not in UML because there is no precondition for an actor, but you can have pre/post conditions for a use case. I encourage you to speak about actor, not about role, use UML wording

Comment: `A "leader" is actually an "employee" but with more privileges (heritage).` Just a word of a caution: generalization between actors `Leader` and `Employee` implies that `Leader` is involved in all the use cases with which `Employee` is involved _including_ `Asking to be promoted` use case which may or may not make sense in your application.

Comment: @vrsio good remark, if inheritance a pre condition must be added to the use case to be promoted

Answer (score 2):

You question is tagged "use-case".  Int this regard, there seems to be a confusion in your question about what an actor really is.  Here is what the UML specs say:

> An Actor models a type of role played by an entity that interacts with the subjects of its associated UseCases. Actors may represent roles played by human users, external hardware, or other systems.

If a user changes role during the interaction with the system,  in the model, it's just like another actor interacts with the system. Example:

- an user interacts with the system with the role of an `Employee` and "executes" some use-cases corresponding to the `Employee` actor;
- this user gets promoted to a `Manager`.
- With the new role, the user may "exectute" use-cases associated with the `Manager` actor.
- A same user may play several roles with the system.  But this does not change the model:  the model is about all the users who have a given role at a given moment, regardless of the individual who performs this role.
- Now in some cases,  one role is a specialization of the other.  This means that all the users having one role also have the other role.  A typical example is if a `Manager` is always an `Employee`.  In this case, you'd show the inheritance in your use-case diagram,  to avoid replicating for `Manager` all the association of `Employee` with use-cases.

If your question is not about use-cases but about classes for authorisation management,  then you'd need to reformulate your question.  But before, have a look at the existing questions on SO, since there are many questions about class diagrams and how to assign users authorisations.

Comment: warning as said by @vrsio in a remark to the question if *Manager* (*Leader* in OP question)  inherits *Employee* that means a *Manager* can ask for to be promoted *Manager*, so that use case must have a precondition to avoid that

Comment: @bruno indeed :-) One could argue that this corresponds to reality: an employee asks to be manager, who later asks to be manager of some managers, and one day perhaps end up asking to become CEO, the manager of all the managers. And maybe such management level is not further relevant for the interactions of the actor with the system ;-)